# How do I run a classic asp webpage from visual studio

Tags: asp-classic

I have two classic asp pages on my local machine that I would like to test them by bring each up in a browser from Visual Studio just to test a few links. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The browser which comes with VS doesn't support Classic ASP, however you can set IIS (which comes with pro versions of windows) or IISExpress (which you need to download and install, but which will work on any version of Windows) your dev server.  IISExpress probably integrates better with VS.